# Command line to restart Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 build service?

Tags: service, command-line, tfs, tfsbuild

Currently when we want to restart the service, we have to 1) log in the server, 2) open the `Administration Console`, 3) hit the restart/start button as below snapshot.

I'm looking for a faster way i.e. a command line to do that locally or via a remote machine.

Please share if you know how to.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a regular Windows Service.  With TFS 2013 you just do:

```
net stop TFSBuildServiceHost.2013
net start TFSBuildServiceHost.2013
```

I assume it's similar for TFS 2012 (just find Visual Studio Team Foundation Build Service Host in your Services listing, go to properties and it will tell you the Service Name that you need to use from the command-line).

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, @DylanSmith is right about the build service for TFS 2012 being named similarly. On my 2012 build server it's `TFSBuildServiceHost.2012`.

Comment: Hi I too want to restart TFS Console programmatically.I want to start service once the machine restart but the above commands are not working for me.Could you please help